# Scalable FQL for: COUNT Facebook FRIENDS who LIKE a Facebook PAGE?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I need an accurate COUNT of FRIENDS that LIKE a Facebook Page (i.e. Friends that are Page Fans).

I'm concerned the following FQL wont scale e.g to a User with 500+ Friends, and Page with 5000+ Likes...

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='PAGE_ID' AND uid IN (
    SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
)
```

Does Facebook limit the number of results returned on FQL queries, or place any limitations on `IN` sub-queries?

To my knowledge, FQL does not support `COUNT`, so I will need to take the results and count them server/client side.

FQL taken from: http://www.leftjoin.net/2011/03/getting-list-of-user-friends-who-like-some-page/

**MY DEMO**: http://www.fbrell.com/saved/8a6e57dbdff4587a563cbb6553ddfb3c?autoRun=false

... Click on "Run Code", then follow the steps ...

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but found it researching FQL.

The limit on results returned is 4999 in FQL, so given you have > 4999 friends that also likes the page you would not get all the results. The limitation (and filtering) is done just before sending the reply to you and should not effect sub-queries.